How to apply a conditional filter to certain variables in tableby function?
I have the following dataframe with tableby.control function and its parameters as follows :
---
title: "Title"
subtitle: "Descriptive analysis"
author:
  - name: AA

date: last-modified


format:
  html:
    page-layout: full
    code-fold: false
    code-tools: false
    embed-resources: true
    self-contained: true
    self-contained-math: true
    df-print: paged
    toc: false
    toc-depth: 3
    toc-location: right
  # pdf:
  #   toc: true
  #   number-depth: 3
  docx:
    prefer-html: true
    echo: false
    warning: false
    toc: false
    reference-doc: 04-Question.docx

format-links: false
editor: visual
---

{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE}

library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(labelled)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(arsenal)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(parameters)

df = data.frame(
  id = 1:12,
  Groups = c(rep("ARM A",5),rep("ARM B",7)),
  procedure = c(rep(c("Yes","No"),5),"No","No"),
  If_yes_Biopsy = c(rep(c("Yes","No"),5),"No","No"),
  If_yes_Dissection = c("Yes","No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","No","No","No","No"),
  Was_there_pain = rep(c("Yes","No"),6),
  If_yes_Abdomen = c("Yes","No","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","No","No","No","Yes","No"),
  If_yes_Leg = c("Yes","No","Yes","No","No","No","No","No","Yes","No","No","No")
)





mycontrols  <- tableby.control(test=TRUE, 
                               total=TRUE,
                               numeric.test="kwt", cat.test="chisq",
                               numeric.stats=c("N", "Nmiss2", "meansd", "medianq1q3", "range"),
                               cat.stats=c("countpct", "Nmiss2"),
                               stats.labels=list(Nmiss2 = "Missing", 
                                                 meansd = "Mean (SD)", 
                                                 medianq1q3 = "Median (Q1, Q3)",
                                                 range = "Min - Max"))



tableby(Groups ~ 
          procedure + 
          If_yes_Biopsy + 
          If_yes_Dissection +
          Was_there_pain +
          If_yes_Abdomen +
          If_yes_Leg,
        data = df, control = mycontrols) %>%
  summary(pfootnote = TRUE, digits=1, digits.pct=1, digits.p=2)


When running the code using Quarto, I have the following output :

I wish that the percentages in variables that start with "if_yes" to take into account the variable before while keeping the same format in table as in the desired outcome

             ARM A (N=5)    ARM B (N=7) Total (N=12)    p value
procedure                                                       
   No           2 (40.0%)   5 (71.4%)   7 (58.3%)   
   Yes          3 (60.0%)   2 (28.6%)   5 (41.7%)   
   Missing      0           0           0   
If_yes_Biopsy                                            
   No           0 (0.0%)    0 (0.0%)    0 (0.0%)
   Yes          3 (100.0%)  2 (100.6%)  5 (100%)    
   Missing      2           5           7   
If_yes_Dissection                                        
   No           1 (33.3%)   2 (100.0%)  3 (33.3%)   
   Yes          2 (66.7%)   0 (0.0%)    2 (66.7%)   
   Missing      2           5           7   
Was_there_pain                                          
   No           2 (40.0%)   4 (57.1%)   6 (50.0%)   
   Yes          3 (60.0%)   3 (42.9%)   6 (50.0%)   
   Missing      0           0           0   
If_yes_Abdomen                                           
   No           1 (33.3%)   1 (33.3%)   2 (33.3%)   
   Yes          2 (66.7%)   2 (66.7%)   4 (66.7%)   
   Missing      2           4           6
If_yes_Leg                                               
   No           1 (33.3%)   2 (66.7%)   3 (50.0%)   
   Yes          2 (66.7%)   1 (33.3%)   3 (50.0%)   
   Missing      2           4           6   

